# can't access array outside of loop in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that retrieves data from a WebSQL db, it then strips off the first letter of each record and builds an array to be displayed later.

I can only access the array in the for loop.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var init;
  var len;
  inits = [];

  var db = openDatabase("contacts", "1.0", "contacts database", 5 * 1024 * 1024);
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM names", [], function(tx, results) {
      len = results.rows.length;
      $("#recordcount ").text(len + " records found");

      for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        var str = results.rows.item(i).lname;
        init = str.substring(0, 1);
        if ($.inArray(init, inits) !== -1) {} else {
          inits.push(init[i]);
        }
$.each(inits, function (index,value){
 alert(index + ":" + value);
});




      };
    });
  });
});
```

when trying to access inits, all I get is undefined unless I access it in the for loop.

```
console.log(inits)
VM112:1 ["H", undefined, undefined]
```

Thx.

Comment: Where are you trying to access it?  And *when* ?

Comment: what does console.log(inits); show? after the loop is finished.

Comment: My guess is if you're trying to access `inits` anywhere outside the `executeSql` callback function, you won't see anything.

Comment: 1)check with console.log(), that inits is defined inside 2)try to create one more function: `function workWithInits(inits)` and call this function inside of `executeSql()`

Comment: nikita, how do I  find out if inits is defined inside?  also, I tried your second suggestion, nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things going on i don't quite understand why,
placements etc..

anyways, give this a go.
(sorry for removing the jquery)

```
  var init;
  var len;
  var inits = [];

  var db = openDatabase("contacts", "1.0", "contacts database", 5 * 1024 * 1024);
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM names", [], function(tx, results) {
      len = results.rows.length;
      recordcount.innerHTML = (len + " records found");

      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var str = results.rows.item(i).lname;
        console.log('str: '+str);
        init = str.substring(0, 1);
        console.log('init: '+init);

        if(inits.indexOf(init) === -1){
            inits.push(init);
        }

      }
      inits.forEach(function( index, value ) {
        console.log(a);
      });

      //Done.
      logIt();
    });
  });
  function logIt(){
      console.log(inits);
  }
```

Comment: that did it, thanks.

Comment: so if anybody is interested, I went back through my code and the code from user2267175 line by line to see what was wrong.  this is what I found.     'for(i=0;i<=len;i++){'   should have been 'for(i=0;i<len;i++){'  lose the = sign.